# Querying for Percent of Change Over Time in App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

My website indexes time series data coming from a feed which is updated continuously. Users of the website should be able to configure alerts which are triggered when the value of a specific attribute in the data has changed by a certain percentage over a certain time period.

Example: lets say we are tracking the number of twitter followers a user has. This is what the (simplified) data feed may look like:

Date, followers

- 10:00, 1
- 10:01, 2
- 10:02, 2
- 10:03, 15
- ...

Alerts:

- Notify me if 'followers' has increased by 15% in the past 1 hour.
- Notify me if 'followers' has decreased by 10% in the past 40 minutes.

There is only one simple data feed. There will (hopefully) be thousands of alerts defined. Many of these alerts may be similar, but it is hard to estimate how many unique ones there will be.

Edit: Forgot to mention this before but number of followers changes quite often (every minute).

What would be the most elegant way of implementing such a mechanism using the datastore and other App Engine facilities? Alerts should be triggered relatively in real time (+/- a few minutes).

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? It seems you could simply override put to do these calculations.

Comment: How would I go about doing this when overriding put? Remember that users may define many alerts, each with a different percent / time combination. When a new record is received via the feed all relevant alerts should trigger. Its possible to do with a datastore query per unique percent / time combination but i would like something more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Overriding put means that the calculations would be done every write, which could be inefficient.  If you allow users to set up these alerts, you will probably end up with datastore objects that represent alerts, which means that there will be gets or queries every time the alerts are evaluated.

One option would be tasks:  When the data feed changes, kick off a task to evaluate the alerts.  At least, this would allow the initial data feed write request to complete faster.  If the data feed is changing rapidly, though, you might have many tasks, and the majority of them would have been rendered unnecessary by more recent data changes.

Maybe the best option is a [cron](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron) task, run every couple of minutes.  You can change the timing of the cron job based upon load, if need be, and if you have many many users/alerts, it would be more feasible to do the processing in a highly parallel way.

Comment: The naive way of going about this, as i suggested is when a new data entry is received, for each unique alert, query the database to find out the historic value (number of followers) and calculate the percent change. Task queues and cron jobs are unrelated details. I'm looking for a method that can achieve the same results with less DB queries. If you have an idea how to pre-calculate the data please explain in detail.

Answer (score 0):

i will try to denormalize your model and find out a balance between performance and redundancy, write ops and read ops.

For example:

1. Since the service focus on real time changes, multiply data for each specific attribute could store together in one datastore. For example, a large entities store all changes for the same user in five days. Thus, the changes over time won't required extra query to compute. 
   It is also the way google host their code jam on app engine. A tree structure can be applied in the datastore to provider some extra features.
2. for the alerts, a common way could be write down who is watching the data changes directly on the data model itself.

Since denormalize really needs to clarify what the use case is, this design is based on my assumption  only.

```
class Watcher(ndb.Model):
    # define the rule such as "Notify me if 'followers' has increased by 15% in the past 1 hour."
    pass


class Attribute(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty() # the name of this attribute such as "twitter_user_1:followers"
    data = ndb.PickleProperty() # a tree store all changes of the specify attribute

    watch_list = ndb.LocalStructureProperty(repeated=True, kind=Watcher) # who want to received the notification
```

Thus, the service can gather all necessary information in one place.

Comment: Thanks but it is not feasible to store all the changes to the  followers in the data property. Followers was just an example, in reality this attribute changes almost every second.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, when you're required to maintain a moving average of a variable, the best thing you can do is go back to where that requirement came from, and see if it can be replaced with a weighted average with exponentially-decaying weights (read the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_decay) explaining it) . It is not as simple to understand as a moving average, but is much simpler to maintain and store, especially if you want to calculate it online and in real time.

Suppose, for example, instead of looking at moving average on the series you provided, you look at the average with decaying weights with half-life of one minute.

- 10:00, 1 (average is 1)
- 10:01, 2 (old average is 1 with weight 0.5, new data is 2, new weighted average is (1*0.5+2*1)/(0.5+1)=**1.667**)
- 10:02, 2 (old average is 1.667 with weight 0.75, new data is 2, new weighted average is (1.667*0.75+2*1)/(0.75+1)=**1.85**)
- 10:03, 15 (old average is 1.85 with weight 0.875, new data is 15, new weighted average is (1.85*0.875+15*1)/(0.875+1)=**8.8667**)
- ...

It may look complicated but it's actually quite simple. Of course, you'd need to adjust the half-life you look at to something that suits your needs (it's a bit different than choosing the window for a moving average).

There are two big advantages to using decaying-weights average over moving average:

1. You don't need to log discrete values to calculate the average; all you need is to store the current value and the time it was sampled.
2. You only need to recalculate the average when a the data changes. When it doesn't change, the weight of the average you have decays, but its value remains. So you can calculate it when new data is received, rather than in a separate task running in `cron` or something of that sort.

P.S., Playing with the equations a little bit, you can find some more useful things you can do with it, such as storing e^X for that value which you can index, as it maintains the ordinal relation between different values of the metric you're monitoring over time.

Answer (score 0):

If your data doesn't need to be updated more than once per-minute per user:

1. Setup the "alerts" in a `LocalStructuredProperty` on the user.
2. When "putting" an incoming data point from the feed, use a pre-put hook to pre-calculate the values:

   - Grab the user entity in the pre-put hook. (If using NDB and you already grab the user, it should come from local memory)
   - Grab all of the "alerts" for that user and process them asynchronously (tasklets)
   - Store everyone's alert data in its own entity, use special key-names to make querying fast (e.g. set they keyname something like `<user>_<alert_type>_<time_in_seconds>_<percentage>` so you can do a `get` instead of a `query`. In this object, store all the data points that come in and fall within the time-limit specified. For one update every minute, you can probably store 1000+ datapoints as a list of tuples `(<timestamp>, <value>)`. From this process the alert based on the configuration defined and store the new value.

Example (tbh. this is a rough example. Should use transactions if you want guarantees on the data):

```
class AlertConfiguration(ndb.Model):
  timespan_in_seconds = ndb.IntegerProperty('tis', indexed=False)
  percent_change = ndb.FloatProperty('pc', indexed=False)

class User(ndb.Model):
  alerts = LocalStructuredProperty(AlertConfiguration, repeated=True, name='a')
  ...

class DataPoint(ndb.Model):
   timestamp = ndb.DateTimeProperty('ts', auto_now_add=True)
   value = ndb.FloatProperty('v')
   user = ndb.KeyProperty(name='u', kind=User)

   def _pre_put_hook(self):
     alerts = self.user.get().alerts
     futures = []
     for alert in alerts:
       futures.append(process_alert(alert, self))
     yield futures

class AlertProcessor(ndb.Model):
  previous_data_points = ndb.JsonProperty(name='pdp', compressed=True)

@ndb.tasklet
def process_alert(alert_config, data_point):
  key_name = '{user}_{timespan}_{percentage}'.format(user=data_point.user.id(), timespan=alert_config.timespan_in_seconds, percentage=alert_config.percent_change)
  processor = yield AlertProcessor.get_or_insert_async(key_name)
  new_points = []
  found = False
  for point in processor.previous_data_points:
     delta = data_point.timestamp - datetime.strptime(point[0], '%c')
     seconds_diff = (86400 * delta.days) + delta.seconds
     if seconds_diff < alert_config.timespan_in_seconds:
       new_points.add(point)
       if not found:
         found = True
         if (data_point.value - point[1]) / data_point.value >= alert_config.percent_change:
            #E-mail alert here?
  new_points.append((data_point.timestamp.strftime('%c'), data_point.value))
  processor.previous_data_points = new_points
  yield processor.put_async()
```

Comment: Thanks @someone1, Three questions: First, why make the data points per user? the system has one global data feed. Second, I'm worried that this won't scale well for thousands of users. Finally, I don't see how is this better then just querying the one feed, per alert on a new datapoint put.

Comment: 1. Well following your Twitter example, I assumed the data was coming in on a per-user basis. If its global, then its global... My only concern then would be how do you know which users have alerts setup on the global feed, do the data-points tell you? I'd probably define a set of alerts to subscribe to and limit my users to that manageable set. 2. This tries to minimize RPC time and put most of the burden on memory/CPU. 3. Well a query will count as 1 read for the query + 1 read for every returned object. Queries also take longer than `get` calls.